# Frontier points of set is always closed

Tags: real-analysis

> consider set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ define $S_{F} = 
> \{ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \textbf{x}\,\, \text{is frontier point of } S  \}$ where a point $ \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a frontier point of set $S$ if every neighborhood of $\textbf{x}$ contains both points in $S$ and $\mathbb{R}^n -S$.prove that $S_{F}$ is *closed*

- we have to show that $S_{F}$ is closed which is equivalent to showing that $\mathbb{R}^n -S_{F}$ is *open*
- consider arbitrary $\textbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^n -S_{F}$ we have to show that there exists $\delta>0$ s.t $B(\textbf{a} , \delta) \subset \mathbb{R}^n - S_{F}$
- assume for contradiction that there is no such $\delta$
- which implies that $\forall \delta>0$ $\exists \textbf{b}  \in B(\textbf{a} , \delta) \cap S_{F}$

and I am struck here, can someone tell how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\forall\ \delta>0 \exists \textbf{b} \in B_{\delta}(\textbf{a}) \cap S_F$, then $\textbf{a}\in (S_F)_F$. But $(S_F)_F\subset S_F$. Then, $\textbf{a}\in S_F$.  For otherwise, $S_F\cap \mathbb{R}^n-S_F=\emptyset$. You can assume previosly that $S_F\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ and $S_F \neq \emptyset$ ('cause both cases are immediate) and you will have your contradiction.

**Another way to see this:**

We can translate your definition of $x\in S_F$ by

$$\forall\ \epsilon>0: B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap S \neq \emptyset \wedge \forall\ \epsilon>0: B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \mathbb{R}^n-S \neq \emptyset $$

If $y\not\in S_F$, then

$$\exists\ \epsilon_0>0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y)\cap S = \emptyset \vee \exists\ \epsilon_0>0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y)\cap \mathbb{R}^n - S = \emptyset $$

if

$$\exists\ \epsilon_0>0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y)\cap \mathbb{R}^n - S = \emptyset$$

Then,

$$\exists\ \epsilon_0 >0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y) \subset S$$
That is, all ball is contained in $\mathbb{R}^n - S_F$. For otherwise, if

$$\exists\ \epsilon_0>0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y)\cap \mathbb{R}^n - S = \emptyset$$

then

$$\exists\ \epsilon_0 >0 : B_{\epsilon_0}(y) \subset \mathbb{R}^n-S$$

For the same reason, we can conclude that $\mathbb{R}^n - S_F$ is open.

Comment: also, your definition seems wrong right ? it shoul be $\forall \epsilon > 0 :  \Big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap S \neq \phi \Big)  \land \Big( B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap \mathbb{R}^n -S \neq \phi \Big) $

Comment: let me explain better

Comment: Now the proof is correct.